# (emacs:804): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion 'source != NULL' failed

Tags: emacs, compiler-errors

I compiled emacs 26.3 and 26.2 in a Linux environment. The compilation seems fine but when I try to run it, the error

```
(emacs:804): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion 'source != NULL' failed
```

showed up.

However, the tool is working just wondering how to solve this warning. Is it glib problem or g_settings_schema or gtk problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with emacs 27.2 when upgrading OS X from 10.14 to 11.2, after which I had to reinstall all of my ports.

I solved it installing gtk3:

`$ sudo port install gtk3`